# what is best practice for handling joint objects passed from web service to angularjs

Tags: angularjs, data-binding

In some cases i pass a mixed set of data from my webservice(in nodejs) to my angularjs Client. 
I'll set an example: in a school database i retrieve data for the teachers who teach the most lessons and the best student for each teacher. so i want to present a table in angularjs holding records for each teacher and student. so this is a mixed object view.
So my question is, if i have a json object retrieved for each teacher and a json object for each student in the database:
**in my angularJS view, should i build a specific javascript object which can manipulate and hold this structure of teacher-student? and then bind the view to this type of object? or is there some other best practice?**
thanks

Comment: do you want to show two seprate tables one for teacher and one for student ?

Comment: No, i want to show a table in which each record would hold a teacher and its best student's details. But this is just an example. What i don't understand is if i should create a specific object to hold the join and then bind it to ui